# Does getstream work together with a browser like js can?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm very new to getstream and I'm having a bit of a hard time thinking about how it can fit into my website let alone trying to figure out how to ask my question on here to get the answer I want

I have a profile page for each user on my site and I want the user to be able to post status updates similar to facebook and also have the option of being notified when another user post an update on their status page if I'm following that user for example. I downloaded the JS/Node version, but don't know how to integrate it into my website.

How does the browser fit in to working with getstream or does it?  I'm basically trying to build a feed on each user's profile page so they can post status updates

I'm surely thinking about this wrong, but how can I essentially populate a div with content using getstream?